# CSS3 Animation Snap Back

Tags: animation, css

I've seen a few questions similar to mine but no real answers.
Is there a way to prevent an snap back once you take your mouse off hovering?

Here is my example...
http://jsfiddle.net/vX7CV/8/

If you un-hover from the element it just snaps back to it's original padding rather than animating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you're after using a transition rather than an animation (which seems more relevant anyway as it's a hover event). I've forked your example: http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/fxL8U/

Comment: Oh Great! I must admit I get confused with the diff between animation, transition and transform.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help but any idea how to fade in a gradient? e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/SparrwHawk/fxL8U/1/ - the gradient just kind of 'pops' in.

Comment: You can't, unfortunately (I think I'm right in saying that CSS gradients can't be animated/transitioned as of yet, though it's in the spec). You can fake it though, with something like this: http://thebigreason.com/blog/2011/01/13/how-to-fade-a-gradient-background-image-with-css-transitions or this: http://www.useragentman.com/blog/csssandpaper-a-css3-javascript-library/

Answer (score 1):

```
ul {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    -webkit-transition: padding 0.2s ease-in-out;
}  

ul:hover {
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}

//OR

ul {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    -webkit-transition: padding 0.2s ease-in-out;

}     
ul:hover {
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}
```